# Expression with Kronecker Delta over upper triangular Matrix

Tags: summation, kronecker-delta

I am having trouble evaluating the following expression involving Kronecker delta's over a double sum restricted over the upper triangular terms:
$$\sum_{c_1=0}^N\sum_{c_2\ge c_1}^N \delta_{c_2,l}\delta_{c_2,k}P_{c_1,c_2}$$
I don't think I can naively just equate $c_2=l=k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\delta_{c_2,l}\delta_{c_2,k}$ vanishes except if both Kronecker symbols are equal to $1$. Which is the case if and only if $c_2=k=l$.

Therefore, either $k=l$ and the given sum is equal to

$$\sum_{c_1=0}^k P_{c_1,k}$$ or $k \ne l$ and in that case, the given sum is equal to zero.

Comment: Could you please explain how you get to the sum you wrote down, when $l=k$?

Comment: For $c_1 \gt k$, $c_2 \ge c_1 \gt k=l$ and for $c_1 \le k$, $c_2=k$ is possible and is the only value for which the product of Kronecker symbols is not equal to zero.